# AlertDialog in Adapter() Error Android Studio

Tags: android

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context:??);
```

I get an error when I put "this"
No "activity.this"

```
@Override
public View getView(final int i, View view, final ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final View v = View.inflate(context, R.layout.trend_2019, null);
    final TextView colorName = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.colorName);
    TextView colorNameEn = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.colorNameEn);
    TextView colorCode = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.colorCode);

    v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("log", colorDataList.get(i).getColorCode());
            AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
            dlg.setNegativeButton("닫기", null);
            dlg.show();
        }
    });
    v.setTag(colorDataList.get(i).getColorCode());



    return v;
}
```

Comment: Hi, if you ask a question with an error you should always provide the error message

Comment: What is your error? There is no `this` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass context in constructor of adapter

```
public class ColorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
     private Context context;
     private List<ColorData> colorDataList;

   public ColorAdapter(Context context, List<ColorData> colorDataList) { 
    this.context = context; 
    this.colorDataList = colorDataList; 
    }
```

and use that `context` in your dialog and you are missing `dlg.create()` in your code

```
AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
                dlg.setNegativeButton("닫기", null);
                dlg.create();
                dlg.show();
```

It will solve that error

Comment: What does xyAdapter say?

Comment: public class ColorAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private List<ColorData> colorDataList;

    public ColorAdapter(Context context, List<ColorData> colorDataList) {
        this.context = context;
        this.colorDataList = colorDataList;
    }

Comment: Edited my answer @박주현

Answer (score -1):

Before show `AlertDialog` you should create it.

Call `create()` before `show()`

**Your edited code**

```
 AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext());
                dlg.setNegativeButton("닫기", null);
                dlg.create();
                dlg.show();
```

Comment: AlertDialog.Builder dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(view.getContext()); view.getContext() is error

Comment: It means that your view's ```Context``` is null. You need to put ```Context``` to the ```Adapter``` too